# VB.NET Form Transparent Background

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

i got picturebox , and new form

when i add my form into the picturebox the background color is **argb(152, 0, 136)**
and i tryied to use `TransparencyKey` and Still the background color is  152, 0, 136
code:

```
Dim frm As New Form
frm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(open.FileName)
frm.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(152, 0, 136)
frm.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(152, 0, 136)
frm.TopLevel = False

PictureBox1.Controls.Add(frm)
frm.show()
```

Comment: What is the full type name of `frm`? You can't add a `System.Windows.Form` object to another control, as it's a top-level component. Don't you mean to add the PictureBox to the form instead?

Comment: i tyied to use picturebox control, but i can't use picturebox because that picturebox not support "Transparent background" and my image is bmp file,  you know how to convert bmp to bmp + Transparent?(when i use TransparentKey the format can be "bmp" or "jpg" and i dont need png)

Comment: The TransparencyKey property can only work on TopLevel windows.  PictureBox already supports transparency well, no tinkering required.

Comment: lets say that i got image with black pixels, and i want that the black pixels = Transparent pixels Like Png how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is tested and functional. I made a new WindowsApplication which added the basic form and a `.vb` code-behind. I added one button to the form. This is the entirety of the code-behind:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub AddTransparentImage()
        Dim pb As PictureBox = New PictureBox
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Pete\Documents\test.bmp")

        bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Black)
        pb.Image = bmp
        pb.Width = bmp.Width
        pb.Height = bmp.Height

        Me.Controls.Add(pb)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddTransparentImage()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `.bmp` is an image with colored text on a black background. When loaded in the form, the background of the image is made transparent.